# MySQL: DELETE permission requires SELECT permission?

Tags: mysql

The user has INSERT and DELETE permissions but not SELECT permission. The user can write records but not read. When trying to "DELETE from my_table WHERE id=5" you get "#1143 select not allowed...". Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: add select permission ?

Comment: The user is not allowed to read (select) because the information should be protected

Comment: Sorry but that's completely dumb, an user who can delete data shouldn't be able to read it ?

Comment: It is not. A user can add records but not delete (prevented by the app) or read them. An admin can add and delete but not read. It is hard to explain but it is about security.

Comment: If you don't trust the Admin, change your Admin.

Comment: The database is used by an app that collects sensitive data. The normal user of the app can add data to the database. The admin can delete data from the database if the admin knows that the data is not correct. There is no user (of the app) who can read from the database. The contents of the database can later be anonymized and exported and used by others.

Answer (score 2):

> Privileges 
>      You need the DELETE privilege on a table to delete rows
>   from it. You need only the SELECT privilege for any columns that are
>   only read, such as those named in the WHERE clause.

[source](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/delete.html)

Conclusion : If you use a **where** in the **Delete** you need the **Select** privilege too.

Comment: With the ordinary ui at the service provider I can only set the permissions for a user of the database i.e. not for a table and not for a column. I am not permitted to set the permission in phpMyAdmin either.